# How to install updates of Nvidia drivers if there is one

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

OK so I had downloaded the drivers from the "Additional Drivers" page but it has been the same version for months. I'm seeing more and more updates on the offical driver page of Nvidia, but I don't know how to install it for Linux. Is there any commands I can type in or anyway to install the drivers that you can download from the official website? OR is my driver up to date and I'm just paranoid? Thanks!

Comment: If everything works OK, there is no need to update drivers. You have the LTS drivers installed. You can use the graphics-drivers PPA, but that may cause some issues. Do not repair what is not broken.

Comment: Oh I see. I just wanted it cause it was the case with windows where keeping old drivers caused frame rate issues in games. For example I see 375 version in the nvidia page for my card and I've been recently suffering from framerate drops. I decided that might have been the cause, so I looked for updates. Thanks regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always install the newest drivers from a PPA

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-xxx
```

Where `xxx` is the driver major version, like 375, 378, etc.

But the PPA is not officially supported.

Comment: I have entered all the commands and it has told me that it finished. Do I need to restart?

Comment: Update: my system settings wont open.  I for some reason cant edit the above post

Comment: I told you not to repair what is not broken. Now you can ask another question with the request to help you out of the current situation.

Comment: It is fine. If I can find a solution to this alongside the driver, it's no loss for me. Thanks.